# Adding json value in yml in python changing the format to yml again

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, yaml, pyyaml

I have to fetch json data and paste it in one of the values in yml. But it is converting it to yml format.

```
{
  "meta": {
    "type": "db",
    "slug": "test",
    "expires": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
    "created": "2016-05-11T22:00:29Z",
    "updated": "2021-11-29T23:36:37Z",
    "createdBy": "Anonymous"
  }
}
```

```
apiVersion: integreatly.org/v1alpha1
kind: GrafanaDashboard
metadata:
  name: testname
  labels:
    app: grafana
    type: dashboard
    folder: proj
spec:
  json: >
```

```
import json
import yaml

# Load files as dicts
with open("sample.json", "r") as f:
    j = json.load(f)
with open("sample.yaml", "r") as f:
    y = yaml.load(f, Loader=yaml.BaseLoader)
# Assign JSON "Slug" to YAML "name".
y['metadata']['name'] = j['meta']['slug']
y['spec']['json'] = j
print(y)
```

I want the output as below

```
apiVersion: integreatly.org/v1alpha1
kind: GrafanaDashboard
metadata:
  name: test
  labels:
    app: grafana
    type: dashboard
    folder: proj
spec:
  json: >
    "meta": {
    "type": "db",
    "slug": "test",
    "expires": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
    "created": "2016-05-11T22:00:29Z",
    "updated": "2021-11-29T23:36:37Z",
    "createdBy": "Anonymous"
  }
```

but with the above script it is showing all the data in dictionary format format. I would like to replace the sampleyaml with the added changes.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have at the end of your YAML document, indicated by `>`, is called a folded scalar string (and in your input file it is empty). So you want to assign the contents of the
JSON file as a string and not as a data structure, **and** use a more modern library than PyYAML that
can easily output/preserve such strings out of the box.

Since you also parse the contents of the JSON file for the `slug` value, you should read in its contents once in a string and parse that:

```py
import sys
from pathlib import Path
import json
import ruamel.yaml


file_in = Path('sample.yaml')
json_in = Path('sample.json')

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.preserve_quotes = True

with json_in.open() as f:
    json_str = f.read()

j = json.loads(json_str)

y = yaml.load(file_in)
y['metadata']['name'] = j['meta']['slug']
# preserve the type folded scalar type
y['spec']['json'] = type(y['spec']['json'])(json_str)

yaml.dump(y, sys.stdout)
```

which gives:

```
apiVersion: integreatly.org/v1alpha1
kind: GrafanaDashboard
metadata:
  name: test
  labels:
    app: grafana
    type: dashboard
    folder: proj
spec:
  json: >
    {
      "meta": {
        "type": "db",
        "slug": "test",
        "expires": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
        "created": "2016-05-11T22:00:29Z",
        "updated": "2021-11-29T23:36:37Z",
        "createdBy": "Anonymous"
      }
    }
```

Comment: Hi its working as expected with the sample json file, but when I try with real tim json file it is showing error like below. File "C:\cygwin64\yaml\conv.py", line 31, in <module>
    with json_in.open() as f:
  File "C:\Users\saikumar.dasari\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\pathlib.py", line 1119, in open
    return self._accessor.open(self, mode, buffering, encoding, errors,
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '1aPuC9KZz-queue-size.json'

Comment: Then you either have the wrong filename, or your file is not in the path. Provide the full path to the jSON file.

Comment: yes. The path is wrong.Its working now. But my requirement is changes to instead of copying whole json file data into yaml value. They want only one of the key value dashboard into. yaml. I have updated the json and required yaml. Could  you please have a look.

Comment: Please don't change your original question, this is not an interactive help service.

Comment: Thank you, I'm able to resolve it by making few changes